# Que tipo de modelagem de sistema é essa?

Tags: delphi, modelagem, arquitetura-de-software, projeto-de-software

já vi em vários locais empresas que desenvolvem sistemas comerciais (*normalmente em DELPHI*) e esses respectivos sistemas são modelados de forma que ficam com um aplicativo "**servidor**" no qual acredito que fica com toda a camada de modelo e acesso a dados (componentes como *dataset*, *connections* e etc) e outros aplicativos (*normalmente pdv, gerenciador, etc.*) se comunicam com ele como se fosse clientes quando necessitam fazer alguma operação no banco de dados, alguém saberia me dizer que tipo de arquitetura/modelagem/padrão de projeto é esse? isso é MVC também?

Ps: Não conheço muito bem o DELPHI

Comment: Se é MVC não temos como saber, só vendo os fontes de cada caso. Isso parece ser o que genericamente chama-se arquitetura cliente-servidor. Cada caso pode funcionar de um jeito específico. Ou pode ser outra coisa, afinal a pergunta não tem um caso concreto, nem detalhes. Não sei o que isso é relevante. Ajudou alguma coisa saber disto? Tem algo que possa mudar para a pergunta ser interessante? Ou podemos fechá-la?

Comment: bigown a pergunta é vaga mesmo justamente porque procurei em todas as partes o que poderia vir a ser esse tipo de padrão de projeto, a principio pensei que fosse algo relacionado a aplicativos distribuídos ou MVC e no fim das contas esperava alguma resposta em relação ao por quê do uso dessa modelagem, nome, benefícios, artigos ou qualquer coisa do tipo, sendo assim vou esperar o pronunciamento de mais alguém que tenha se deparado com essa mesma ocasião, caso contrário irei fechar o tópico, obrigado.

Comment: Isso é o velho modelo cliente/servidor...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amigo esse tipo de aplicação é chamada de aplicação 3 camadas.

Sendo elas:

**1º Data Tier** (Camada da Base de Dados) (SQL, SQLLite,etc)

**2º Business Logic Tier** (Camada da regra de negócios), chamado de servidor de aplicações, pois ela que disponibiliza os métodos para serem consumidos pela aplicação cliente, que por sua vez desconhecem a primeira camada.

**3º Presentation Tier** (Camada Cliente), que é a aplicação que consome os métodos da segunda camada.

Antigamente era muito comum as empresas de softwares adotarem esta metodologia pois ela permite utilizar os métodos disponibilizados pela aplicação servidora por diversos aplicativos clientes de forma relativamente rápida.

Fora isso existia na época em alguns casos a necessidade de reduzir custos com licenças adicionais cobradas por usuários para utilização da aplicação SGDB (SQL Server, Oracle) e com este tipo de arquitetura é possível que a aplicação servidora seja configurada para que utilize apenas uma conexão para realização das consultas, desta forma evitando o gasto com licenças adicionais. Vale lembrar que com esta abordagem com o passar do tempo a performance é afetada.

Embora possua a separação da regra de negócios da interface gráfica, este modelo não é considerado um MVC pois não necessariamente o aplicativo servidor trafega um objeto diretamente para atualizar a view como no padrão MVC e nem mesmo possui necessariamente um controller (embora possa vir a possuir dependendo da modelagem utilizada), note que neste caso da aplicação servidora no geral são disponibilizado apenas métodos que devolvem datasets ou resultados de um calculo especifico, stringlists, valores booleanos para validações de acesso por exemplo, etc.

Atualmente ainda é utilizada esta abordagem devido a praticidade de se reutilizar código em diversas aplicações isso deve-se tambem ao fato do surgimento do firemonkey possibilitando o desenvolvimento para dispositivos moveis, que podem consumir os métodos do servidor de aplicação.

O datasnap utiliza este conceito e atualmente possui recursos a mais para que seja possível de forma mais simples trafegar objetos entre as aplicações usando json ou xml por exemplo.

Alem do datasnap existem outros frameworks como o da [synapse](http://synopse.info/fossil/wiki?name=SQLite3%20Framework) e o [data abstract](http://www.dataabstract.com/da/default.aspx) da rem objects que também auxiliam no desenvolvimento deste tipo de aplicação.

Comment: Acho que isso tira minha dúvida, obrigado!